# Trying to call Audio.stopAudio() causes InvalidStateError

Tags: ios, audio, three.js, aframe

When I call Audio.stopAudio() on iOS, it causes an InvalidStateError. It cites three.js:38399. Has anyone run into this issue with Three.js / A-Frame before?

I have tried using native audio: causes permissions error on iOS.
I have tried using Three.js: same issue as the error in A-Frame because A-Frame is using Three.js.

I want to be able to play, pause and stop audio in A-Frame for our project. The first clip plays okay but then the error is thrown when it is stopped to play the second.

Comment: Maybe audio hasn't loaded yet or is not playing?

Comment: Interesting idea. I tried switching the stopAudio to pauseAudio and it was able to switch. However when I come back to the audio file to replay it, it is obviously part of the way through. Also, when the audio file goes to loop it throughs a similar error:

'InvalidStateError: The object is in an invalid state.'
This one is throwing because of start and cites: three.js:38359.

Comment: Also, as a follow up.. the console.warn is not being called at three.js:38340.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the idea from @ngokevin, I went and dug through the code to seen where it might be stopping the animation prematurely. Turns out when you pause an A-Frame scene it stops the audio. This causes the issues I was seeing. I now am using a restart type functionality instead of a pause functionality for when I do my camera swap. Works much better.